# Magento 2 custom sessions not consistent

Tags: php, session, magento, magento2

I have created my own magento sessions using [this guide](https://blog.e-zest.com/custom-sessions-in-magento-2), but the sessions are so fickle its driving me crazy!

I have created a list of session functions so all session setters, getters and unsetters are using the session model.

For example, there are plenty of functions like these in my **app/code/MyModule/MySession/Model/Session.php** file

```
//Set the car model from the session
public function setSessionCarModel($value){
    return $this->_session->setCarModel($value);
}

//Get the car model from the session
public function getSessionCarModel(){
    return $this->_session->getCarModel();
}

//Unset the car model from the session
public function unsetSessionCarModel(){
    return $this->_session->unsCarModel();
}
```

I am then trying to set, get and unset my sessions in multiple places across my site, a few examples are these (I know I shouldn't really be using the object manager in the .phtml files before it gets noted)

**.phtml**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customSession = $objectManager->create('\MyModule\MySession\Model\Session');
$carModel = $customSession->getSessionCarModel();
```

**Ajax file**

```
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Controller\Ajax;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory; 

class Index extends Action {
    protected $_customSession;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \MyModule\MySession\Model\Session $customSession
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_customSession = $customSession;
    }


    public function execute(){
            $this->_customSession->setSessionCarModel(1);
    }
}
```

And multiple other places across the site, but for some reason my sessions don't seem to be consistent, and its driving me insane!

Sometimes it doesn't set them at all, sometimes it grabs old values, etc.

Am I doing something wrong with the way i'm implementing custom sessions?

If anyone could help shine a light on this i'd be very grateful!

> > Magento Version - 2.3.2
> >
> > Session Store method - Files
> >
> > Mode - Development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code pasted in the phtml file would give problems. Because you are using the object manager directly. This would give inconsistent results, especially if you are trying to access information that depends on the application context. Sessions / Cookies are all such examples.

In your phtml file, you can use JavaScript to query your ajax controller and get session data from there. Already wrote a similar answer here:

[Magento 2 session unsetting itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58285760/magento-2-session-unsetting-itself/58418150#58418150)

Comment: So basically all of my session manipulation needs to be done via the controllers and never in the template file and it should be consistent?

Comment: Can I call my custom session in any controller and it will be consistent, or would I need to manipulate all of my sessions in the 1 controller?

Comment: Correct. All session manipulation should be done ideally in Controllers or Models. Once you set your custom session through a Controller, it should remain consistent throughout the session's lifetime (it's set in the admin) or until the session cookie is deleted.